# Alto del select automático

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, css3

Tengo un select con un texto muy largo, el ancho del select es del 100% porlo tanto el texto es mas largo que el 100% del select entonces me gustaría que el texto se mostrase entero en el select haciendo un salto de parrafo

```
    <select>
       <option>Prueba de texto muuy largo Prueba de texto muy largo<option>
    </select>
```

ME gustaría que apareciese con un salto de linea modificando el height del select para que muestre todo el texto del campo option

```
    -----------------------------
    Prueba de texto muuy largo 
    Prueba de texto muy largo
    -----------------------------
```

Actualmente se muestra así

```
    -----------------------------
    Prueba de texto muuy largo Pr
    -----------------------------
```

```css
div.nav-anchor select {
    width: 100%;
    //height: 50px;
    background-color: @color-grey-08;
    border: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
}
```

```html
      <select name="dropdpown" id="select-anchor">
        <option>
          Tesxto extremadamente largo, texto muy muy largo, muy muy largo
        </option> 
      </select>
```

Gracias de antemano!

Comment: ¿Podrías compartir la hoja de estilos que afecte a ese `<select>` o el atributo `style` que hayas usado? ¿Podrías indicar por qué no te viene bien que aumente el tamaño a lo ancho?

Comment: Si, voy a compartirlo, no puede ser a lo ancho por que es una versión móvil que tiene 2 columnas en 1 de las columnas está el select, por lo tanto no cabe el texto, debe ser a lo alto

Comment: Las etiquetas `<select>` no soportan contenidos multilínea, pero podrías emular el funcionamiento mediante javascript y CSS. ¿Eso es lo que deseas?

Comment: Exacto @OscarGarcia

Comment: Echa un vistazo a esto: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45635038/make-div-and-ul-act-like-a-select-element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45635038/make-div-and-ul-act-like-a-select-element)